# razor pages BindProperty not working on hidden peroperties

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

From the below models ReportType_AdHoc & ReportType_PushReport are properly binded so that when OnPost() occurs, these values are persistent from what was selected on screen. However, the Pager properties are not even though I tried including them as hidden fields inside the form but that doesn't seem to help? I always see error "pager == null". What am I doing wrong with BindProperty - How can I make the Pager class properties persistent?

My Models:

```
public class MyReportModel
{
    public MyReportParams myReportParams { get; set; }
    public Pager pager { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Reports> results { get; set; }
}

public class Pager
{
    public float pageResults { get; set; } = 100f;
    public double pageCount { get; set; }
    public int pageNumber { get; set; }
    public int resultsCount { get; set; }
}
public class MyReportParams
{
    [Display(Name = "AdHoc")]
    public bool ReportType_AdHoc { get; set; };
    [Display(Name = "Push Report")]
    public bool ReportType_PushReport { get; set; };
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    . . .

    [BindProperty]
    public  MyReportModel myReportModel { get; set; }

    . . .
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (myReportModel.myReportParams == null)
             _logger.LogInformation("myReportParams == null");
        if (myReportModel.pager == null)
             _logger.LogInformation("pager == null");
        . . .
    }

    . . .
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<form method="post">

  . . .

  <input type="hidden" name="myReportModel" asp-for="myReportModel" />
  <input type="hidden" name="pager"  asp-for="myReportModel.pager" />
  <input type="hidden" name="pageCount"  asp-for="myReportModel.pager.pageCount" />
  <input type="hidden" name="resultsCount"  asp-for="myReportModel.pager.resultsCount" />
  <input type="hidden" name="pageNumber"  asp-for="myReportModel.pager.pageNumber" />
  <input type="hidden" name="pageResults"  asp-for="myReportModel.pager.pageResults" />

  . . .

  <div class="form-row form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
          <h6 class="float-left">Report Type:</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-light border rounded border-success col-sm-10">
          <div class="float-left col-sm-2">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="myReportModel.myReportParams.ReportType_AdHoc">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" asp-for="myReportModel.myReportParams.ReportType_AdHoc"></label>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="float-left col-sm-2">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="myReportModel.myReportParams.ReportType_PushReport">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" asp-for="myReportModel.myReportParams.ReportType_PushReport"></label>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  . . .
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between the feedback on inspecting the elements value and eliminating name attribute I was able to have success. Here is an example of what the final hidden field that works looks like:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="myReportModel.pager.pageCount" value="@Model.myReportModel.pager.pageCount"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Be sure **the hidden inputs contain value**(press F12 in the browser and check the `Elements`).

2.Model Binding binds the property by `name` attribute. `asp-for` will generate the `name` attribute, but if you specify the `name` it will override tag helper generated name.

3.`myReportModel.pager.propertyName` is the correct name for binding. Just remove the `name` attribute in each input element will works fine. Besides, input with `asp-for="myReportModel"` and  `asp-for="myReportModel.pager"` are useless. Tag helper cannot generate the value for the complex model. Suggest you can remove them:

```
<form method="post">
    @*<input type="hidden" name="myReportModel" asp-for="myReportModel" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pager"  asp-for="myReportModel.pager" />*@
    <input type="hidden"  asp-for="myReportModel.pager.pageCount" />
    <input type="hidden"  asp-for="myReportModel.pager.resultsCount" />
    <input type="hidden"  asp-for="myReportModel.pager.pageNumber" />
    <input type="hidden"  asp-for="myReportModel.pager.pageResults" />

    <div class="form-row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <h6 class="float-left">Report Type:</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-light border rounded border-success col-sm-10">
            <div class="float-left col-sm-2">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="myReportModel.myReportParams.ReportType_AdHoc">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" asp-for="myReportModel.myReportParams.ReportType_AdHoc"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left col-sm-2">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="myReportModel.myReportParams.ReportType_PushReport">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" asp-for="myReportModel.myReportParams.ReportType_PushReport"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="post" />
</form>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Model binding can be a little weird, particularly if you don't provide any explicit `[BindProperty(Name = "...")]`. Or when you don't use name prefixes in your form values.

At each level of your model, if no value is found with the name of the property, the model binder will attempt to bind the object from an empty prefix.

This can cause some weird model binding errors. Particularly noticeable when you have a collection property to bind, but don't provide any actual values for that collection.

Since you have provided an explicit value for `name="pager"`, even though it is a class and has no value itself, all child properties must have that name as a prefix. Either as dot or array notation. eg `name="pager.pageCount"`.

You'll find it much easier to just let the `asp-for="..."` tag helper define all the input names. Using explicit `BindProperty` attributes if you wish to override them.

Comment: Thanks for the input: This is what it took for me to get it going - Set the "value" attribute.

                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="myReportModel.pager.pageCount" value="@Model.myReportModel.pager.pageCount"/>